Char array in c getting modified unexpectedly and removing an unused variable breaks the algorithm
so i made a simple AES algorithm for my college assignment. the algorithm it self works fine i get no error both the cipher text and decryptedText is fine however when i try to access the decryptedtext it gets altered.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>

typedef struct {
    int bits[4][4][8];
}Block;

int SBox[16][16] = {
    {  99, 124, 119, 123, 242, 107, 111, 197,  48,   1, 103,  43, 254, 215, 171, 118 },
    { 202, 130, 201, 125, 250,  89,  71, 240, 173, 212, 162, 175, 156, 164, 114, 192 },
    { 183, 253, 147,  38,  54,  63, 247, 204,  52, 165, 229, 241, 113, 216,  49,  21 },
    {   4, 199,  35, 195,  24, 150,   5, 154,   7,  18, 128, 226, 235,  39, 178, 117 },
    {   9, 131,  44,  26,  27, 110,  90, 160,  82,  59, 214, 179,  41, 227,  47, 132 },
    {  83, 209,   0, 237,  32, 252, 177,  91, 106, 203, 190,  57,  74,  76,  88, 207 },
    { 208, 239, 170, 251,  67,  77,  51, 133,  69, 249,   2, 127,  80,  60, 159, 168 },
    {  81, 163,  64, 143, 146, 157,  56, 245, 188, 182, 218,  33,  16, 255, 243, 210 },
    { 205,  12,  19, 236,  95, 151,  68,  23, 196, 167, 126,  61, 100,  93,  25, 115 },
    {  96, 129,  79, 220,  34,  42, 144, 136,  70, 238, 184,  20, 222,  94,  11, 219 },
    { 224,  50,  58,  10,  73,   6,  36,  92, 194, 211, 172,  98, 145, 149, 228, 121 },
    { 231, 200,  55, 109, 141, 213,  78, 169, 108,  86, 244, 234, 101, 122, 174,   8 },
    { 186, 120,  37,  46,  28, 166, 180, 198, 232, 221, 116,  31,  75, 189, 139, 138 },
    { 112,  62, 181, 102,  72,   3, 246,  14,  97,  53,  87, 185, 134, 193,  29, 158 },
    { 225, 248, 152,  17, 105, 217, 142, 148, 155,  30, 135, 233, 206,  85,  40, 223 },
    { 140, 161, 137,  13, 191, 230,  66, 104,  65, 153,  45,  15, 176,  84, 187,  22 }
};

int SBoxInverse[16][16] = {
    {  82,   9, 106, 213,  48,  54, 165,  56, 191,  64, 163, 158, 129, 243, 215, 251},
    { 124, 227,  57, 130, 155,  47, 255, 135,  52, 142,  67,  68, 196, 222, 233, 203},
    {  84, 123, 148,  50, 166, 194,  35,  61, 238,  76, 149,  11,  66, 250, 195,  78},
    {   8,  46, 161, 102,  40, 217,  36, 178, 118,  91, 162,  73, 109, 139, 209,  37},
    { 114, 248, 246, 100, 134, 104, 152,  22, 212, 164,  92, 204,  93, 101, 182, 146},
    { 108, 112,  72,  80, 253, 237, 185, 218,  94,  21,  70,  87, 167, 141, 157, 132},
    { 144, 216, 171,   0, 140, 188, 211,  10, 247, 228,  88,   5, 184, 179,  69,   6},
    { 208,  44,  30, 143, 202,  63,  15,   2, 193, 175, 189,   3,   1,  19, 138, 107},
    {  58, 145,  17,  65,  79, 103, 220, 234, 151, 242, 207, 206, 240, 180, 230, 115},
    { 150, 172, 116,  34, 231, 173,  53, 133, 226, 249,  55, 232,  28, 117, 223, 110},
    {  71, 241,  26, 113,  29,  41, 197, 137, 111, 183,  98,  14, 170,  24, 190,  27},
    { 252,  86,  62,  75, 198, 210, 121,  32, 154, 219, 192, 254, 120, 205,  90, 244},
    {  31, 221, 168,  51, 136,   7, 199,  49, 177,  18,  16,  89,  39, 128, 236,  95},
    {  96,  81, 127, 169,  25, 181,  74,  13,  45, 229, 122, 159, 147, 201, 156, 239},
    { 160, 224,  59,  77, 174,  42, 245, 176, 200, 235, 187,  60, 131,  83, 153,  97},
    {  23,  43,   4, 126, 186, 119, 214,  38, 225, 105,  20,  99,  85,  33,  12, 125}
};

Block getBlock(char pt[],int nthBlock) {
    Block block;
    char HexToBinary[16][4] = {"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};
    int index = nthBlock * 32,i,j,h = -1,k;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                if(k % 4 == 0) h++;
                char currentChar = index+h < (int)strlen(pt) ? pt[index+h] : '0';
                int hex = currentChar - ((currentChar >= '0' && currentChar <= '9') ? '0' : ('A' - 10));
                block.bits[j][i][k] = HexToBinary[hex][k % 4] - '0';
            }
        }
    }

    return block;
}

Block getKeyBlock(int key[]){
    char HexToBinary[16][4] = {"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};
    Block block;
    int i,j,h = 0,k;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++,h++) {
            int v1 = (key[h] >> 4) & 0x0F;
            int v2 = key[h] & 0x0F;
            for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) block.bits[j][i][k] = HexToBinary[k < 4 ? v1 : v2][k % 4] - '0';
        }
    }

    return block;
}

void printBlockH(Block block,char title[],int n){
    int i,j,k;
    printf("\n\t%s [%02d] : ",title,n);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) printf("%d",block.bits[i][j][k]);
            printf("  ");
        }
    }
}

void printBlock(Block block,char title[],int n){
    int i,j;
    printf("\n%s [%02d] : \n",title,n);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            int val = block.bits[i][j][0] * 128 + block.bits[i][j][1] * 64 + block.bits[i][j][2] * 32 + block.bits[i][j][3] * 16 + block.bits[i][j][4] * 8 + block.bits[i][j][5] * 4 + block.bits[i][j][6] * 2 + block.bits[i][j][7];
            printf("%02x ",val);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void printColumn(int col[4][8],char title[],int n){
    int i;
    printf("\n%s [%02d] : \n",title,n);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int val = col[i][0] * 128 + col[i][1] * 64 + col[i][2] * 32 + col[i][3] * 16 + col[i][4] * 8 + col[i][5] * 4 + col[i][6] * 2 + col[i][7];
        printf("%02x\n",val);
    }
}

Block SBoxBlock(Block block){
    int i,j,h,k;
    Block newBlock = {};
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            k = block.bits[i][j][0] * 8 + block.bits[i][j][1] * 4 + block.bits[i][j][2] * 2 + block.bits[i][j][3];
            h = block.bits[i][j][4] * 8 + block.bits[i][j][5] * 4 + block.bits[i][j][6] * 2 + block.bits[i][j][7];
            int sBoxResult = SBox[k][h];
            for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--) {
                newBlock.bits[i][j][k] = sBoxResult & 1;
                sBoxResult >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return newBlock;
}

Block SBoxBlockInverse(Block block){

    int i,j,h,k;
    Block newBlock = {};
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            k = block.bits[i][j][0] * 8 + block.bits[i][j][1] * 4 + block.bits[i][j][2] * 2 + block.bits[i][j][3];
            h = block.bits[i][j][4] * 8 + block.bits[i][j][5] * 4 + block.bits[i][j][6] * 2 + block.bits[i][j][7];
            int sBoxResult = SBoxInverse[k][h];
            for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--) {
                newBlock.bits[i][j][k] = sBoxResult & 1;
                sBoxResult >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return newBlock;
}

void SBoxColumn(int c1[4][8],int c2[][8]){
    int i,h,k;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        k = c1[i][0] * 8 + c1[i][1] * 4 + c1[i][2] * 2 + c1[i][3];
        h = c1[i][4] * 8 + c1[i][5] * 4 + c1[i][6] * 2 + c1[i][7];
        int sBoxResult = SBox[k][h];
        for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--) {
            c2[i][k] = sBoxResult & 1;
            sBoxResult >>= 1;
        }
    }
}

void SBoxColumnInverse(int c1[4][8],int c2[][8]){

    int i,h,k;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        k = c1[i][0] * 8 + c1[i][1] * 4 + c1[i][2] * 2 + c1[i][3];
        h = c1[i][4] * 8 + c1[i][5] * 4 + c1[i][6] * 2 + c1[i][7];
        int sBoxResult = SBoxInverse[k][h];
        for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--) {
            c2[i][k] = sBoxResult & 1;
            sBoxResult >>= 1;
        }
    }
}

Block ShiftRows(Block block){
    Block newBlock = {};
    int i,j,k,n = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++,n++) for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) newBlock.bits[i][j][k] = block.bits[i][(j+n) % 4][k];
    return newBlock;
}

Block ShiftRowsInverse(Block block){
    Block newBlock = {};
    int i,j,k,n = 0;
    int indexes[4][4] = {
        {0,1,2,3},
        {3,0,1,2},
        {2,3,0,1},
        {1,2,3,0}
    };
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++,n++) for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) newBlock.bits[i][j][k] = block.bits[i][indexes[n][j]][k];
    return newBlock;
}

void Xor(int a[9],int b[8],int *r){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) r[i] = a[i+1] ^ b[i];
}

void XorColumn(int a[4][8],int b[4][8],int c[][8]){
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) for(j = 0; j < 8; j++) c[i][j] = a[i][j] ^ b[i][j];
}

int GaloisMult(int a, int b){
    int i,j=0,h=0,k,abits[8],bbits[8],rbits[8];
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(((a >> i) & 1) != 0) abits[j++] = i;
        if(((b >> i) & 1) != 0) bbits[h++] = i;
    }
    int dbits[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (k = 0; k < h; k++) for (i = 0; i < j; i++) dbits[10 - abits[i] + bbits[k]] = (dbits[10 - abits[i] + bbits[k]] + 1) % 2;

    int val = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) val = (val << 1) | dbits[i];
    while(val > 0xff) val ^= 0x11b;
    return val;
}

Block MixColumn(Block block){

    int i,j,k;
    int m1[4][4] = {
        {2,3,1,1},
        {1,2,3,1},
        {1,1,2,3},
        {3,1,1,2}
    };

    int m2[4][4];
    int result[4][4] = {
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0}
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) m2[i][j] = block.bits[i][j][0] * 128 + block.bits[i][j][1] * 64 + block.bits[i][j][2] * 32 + block.bits[i][j][3] * 16 + block.bits[i][j][4] * 8 + block.bits[i][j][5] * 4 + block.bits[i][j][6] * 2 + block.bits[i][j][7];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) result[j][i] ^= GaloisMult(m2[k][i],m1[j][k]);

    Block newBlock = {};
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            int val = result[i][j];
            for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--) {
                newBlock.bits[i][j][k] = val & 1;
                val >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return newBlock;
}

Block MixColumnInverse(Block block){

    int i,j,k;
    int m1[4][4] = {
        {14,11,13,9},
        {9,14,11,13},
        {13,9,14,11},
        {11,13,9,14},
    };

    int m2[4][4];
    int result[4][4] = {
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0}
    };

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) m2[i][j] = block.bits[i][j][0] * 128 + block.bits[i][j][1] * 64 + block.bits[i][j][2] * 32 + block.bits[i][j][3] * 16 + block.bits[i][j][4] * 8 + block.bits[i][j][5] * 4 + block.bits[i][j][6] * 2 + block.bits[i][j][7];

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) result[j][i] ^= GaloisMult(m2[k][i],m1[j][k]);

    Block newBlock = {};
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            int val = result[i][j];
            for (k = 7; k >= 0; k--) {
                newBlock.bits[i][j][k] = val & 1;
                val >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return newBlock;
}

Block AddRoundKey(Block block,Block key){
    Block newBlock = {};
    int i,j,k;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) newBlock.bits[i][j][k] = block.bits[i][j][k] ^ key.bits[i][j][k];
    return newBlock;
}

void GetColumn(Block b,int col[][8],int x,int n){
    int i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) for(j = 0; j < 8; j++) col[i][j] = b.bits[(i+n) % 4][x][j];
}

int ConvertToASCII(int bits[8],int start) {
    int i = bits[start] * 8 + bits[start + 1] * 4 + bits[start + 2] * 2 + bits[start + 3];
    return i;
}

void BlockToASCII(char *text,Block b) {
    char HexToChar[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int i,j,h = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            int c = ConvertToASCII(b.bits[j][i],0);
            int c2 = ConvertToASCII(b.bits[j][i],4);
            text[h++] = HexToChar[c];
            text[h++] = HexToChar[c2];
        }
    }
    text[h] = '\0';
}

char getHexFromChar(unsigned char c,int n){
    char HexToChar[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    return HexToChar[(n == 0) ? c / 16 : (c % 16)];
}

int indexOf(char c){
    char HexToChar[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) if(c == HexToChar[i]) return i;
    return -1;
}

char getCharFromHex(char a,char b){
    int s = indexOf(a) * 16 + indexOf(b);
    return (char)s;
}

void Encrypt(char* OutText,char InText[],Block key0,Block Ki[10]){

    float PlainTextInBlocks = strlen(InText)*4 / 128;
    float extraBlock = fmod(strlen(InText)*4 / 128.0f,1.0f) > 0.0f ? 1 : 0;
    
    int BlocksRequired = (int)PlainTextInBlocks + extraBlock;

    int i,j;
    Block blocks[BlocksRequired];
    for(i = 0; i < BlocksRequired; i++) blocks[i] = getBlock(InText,i);
    for(i = 0; i < BlocksRequired; i++) printBlock(blocks[i],"Block",i);
    
    for (i = 0; i < BlocksRequired; i++){
        Block block = blocks[i];
        
        Block inp = AddRoundKey(block,key0);
        // printBlock(inp,"inp",i);
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            Block sb = SBoxBlock(inp);
            // printBlock(sb,"sb",j);
            Block sft = ShiftRows(sb);
            // printBlock(sft,"sft",j);
            Block mc = MixColumn(sft);
            // printBlock(mc,"mx",j);
            inp = AddRoundKey((j != 9) ? mc : sft,Ki[j]);
            // printBlock(inp,"inp",j);
        }
        // printBlock(inp,"inp",i);
        char text[33];
        BlockToASCII(text,inp);
        strcat(OutText,text);
    }
}

void Decrypt(char* OutText,char InText[],Block key0,Block Ki[10]){

    float PlainTextInBlocks = strlen(InText)*4 / 128;
    float extraBlock = fmod(strlen(InText)*4 / 128.0f,1.0f) > 0.0f ? 1 : 0;
    
    int BlocksRequired = (int)PlainTextInBlocks + extraBlock;

    int i,j;
    Block blocks[BlocksRequired];
    for(i = 0; i < BlocksRequired; i++) blocks[i] = getBlock(InText,i);
    for(i = 0; i < BlocksRequired; i++) printBlock(blocks[i],"Block",i);
    
    for (i = 0; i < BlocksRequired; i++){
        Block block = blocks[i];
        Block inp = AddRoundKey(block,Ki[9]);
        // printBlock(inp,"inp",i);
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
            Block sft = ShiftRowsInverse(inp);
            // printBlock(sft,"sft",j);
            Block sb = SBoxBlockInverse(sft);
            // printBlock(sb,"sb",j);
            // printBlock((j == 9) ? key0 : Ki[8-j],"Ki",j);
            Block add = AddRoundKey(sb,(j == 9) ? key0 : Ki[8-j]);
            // printBlock(add,"add",j);
            inp = (j == 9) ? add : MixColumnInverse(add);
            // printBlock(inp,"inp",j);
        }
        // printBlock(inp,"inp",i);
        char text[33];
        BlockToASCII(text,inp);
        strcat(OutText,text);
    }
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int i = 0,j = 0,n = 0,k = 0,l = 0;
    char cipherText[] = "";
    char DecryptedText[] = "";
    char rawInput[1024];
    // int key[16] = {43,126,21,22,40,174,210,166,171,247,21,136,9,207,79,60};
    int key[16] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15};

    puts("Enter Plain Text : ");
    gets(rawInput);
    n = strlen(rawInput);
    // char plaintext[] = "3243F6A8885A308D313198A2E0370734";
    // while(n % 16 != 0) n++;
    char plaintext[(n * 2) + 1];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        plaintext[j++] = getHexFromChar(i < (int)strlen(rawInput) ? rawInput[i] : ' ',0);
        plaintext[j++] = getHexFromChar(i < (int)strlen(rawInput) ? rawInput[i] : ' ',1);
    }
    plaintext[j] = '\0';

    // for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) key[i] = rand() % 16;
    Block OriginalKey = getKeyBlock(key);
    printf("\nRandom Key              : ");
    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) printf("%X", key[i]);
    printf("\n");

    int rtemp[10] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x20, 0x40, 0x80, 0x1B, 0x36};
    int RCon[10][4][8];
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) RCon[i][j][k] = (((j == 0) ? rtemp[i] : 0) >> (7-k)) & 1;
    Block Ki[10];
    Block temp = OriginalKey;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        int c1[4][8],c2[4][8],c3[4][8],out[4][8];
        for (l = 0; l < 4; l++){
            GetColumn(temp,c1,(l == 0) ? 3 : l-1,(l == 0) ? 1 : 0);
            GetColumn(temp,c2,l,0);
            if(l == 0){
                SBoxColumn(c1,c3);
                XorColumn(c2,c3,c1);
                for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) c2[j][k] = RCon[i][j][k];
            }
            XorColumn(c1,c2,out);
            for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) temp.bits[j][l][k] = out[j][k];
        }
        Ki[i] = temp;
    }

    printBlock(OriginalKey,"KeyInitial",0);

    printf("Plain Text In Hex       : %s",plaintext);
    
    printf("\n\nEncryption      ->");
    Encrypt(cipherText,plaintext,OriginalKey,Ki);
    printf("\n\nCipher Text In Hex      : %s\n",cipherText);

    printf("\nDecryption      ->");
    Decrypt(DecryptedText,cipherText,OriginalKey,Ki);
    printf("\n\nDecrypted Text In Hex   : %s\n",DecryptedText);
//this is line 473
    int len = (int)strlen(DecryptedText);
    printf("len size  : %d\n",len);
    printf("aften len msg  : %s\n",DecryptedText);
    printf("aften len msg Size  : %d\n",(int)strlen(DecryptedText));
    char rawOutput[len / 2 + 1];
    printf("after raw output msg  : %s\n",DecryptedText);
    printf("after raw output msg Size   : %d\n",(int)strlen(DecryptedText));
    for (i = 0,j = 0; i < len / 2; i++){
        rawOutput[i] = getCharFromHex(DecryptedText[j],DecryptedText[j+1]);
        j += 2;
    }
    rawOutput[i] = '\0';
    printf("\nOriginal Text   : %s\n",rawOutput);

    return 0;
}


the algorithm works fine until line 473 just before that on line 472 i print the Decrypted text and it is the correct text in hex format but now from line 473 i am converting that to ascii output.
the problem is after line 473 the decrypted text gets shorter and shorter and the ascii output comes out wrong.
the output:
...other outputs
Decrypted Text In Hex   : 4A696D6D790000000000000000000000
len size  : 32
aften len   : 4A696D6D79 
aften len Size  : 11
after raw output   : 4A∟█a
after raw output Size   : 5

Original Text   : J∩∩∩∩∩∩

the 2nd problem is at line 212 where i have an unused int rbits[8] if i remove that unused variable the algorithm breaks and i get all wrong results.

This code is far too long for a SO question. Reduce it to the minimal example which has the same erratic behaviour. It is not a free debugging service.

Please post a [mre] with emphasis on minimal.

The fact that removing an unused variable braks the algoritghm is a strong hint that you have an overflow somewhere

it doesnt work if i remove the AES algorithm functions. :(

you can just copy paste this and run to see the error

char cipherText[] = ""; and char DecryptedText[] = ""; will overflow PDQ. You have char rawInput[1024]; so those two must have that size too.

Warning: function gets() is obsolete and is no longer part of the standard C library. Please read Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?

if i do char ciphertext[any value] the strcat doesnt work because it then appends the new values

@JaiminVashi there is at least an other buffer overflow in this line dbits[10 - abits[i] + bbits[k]] = (dbits[10 - abits[i] + bbits[k]] + 1) % 2;, the expression 10 - abits[i] + bbits[k] becomes 13 (maybe  even a higher value), but dbits has only 11 entries...

You need char ciphertext[1024] = ""; to be able to concatenate.

abits[i] for any given i can be at max 7 and bbits[k] will be max 3 so abits[i] + bbits[k] <= 10 hence dbits[10 - 10]  will be max and it cant go 11

An index of 10 needs a length of 11.

@WeatherVane this works but now i cant have more then the mentioned amount input. which is acceptable too because no one will use this but the 2nd problem still persists.

@WeatherVane dbits is initialized as int dbits[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; 11 0s

@JaiminVashi well, the index got up to 13. If you don't believe it, put a printf and see what is displ,ayed.

@Jabberwocky if i print simple abits+bbits the max i get is 10 and if i print 10 - a+b i get 13

@JaiminVashi well, you've found the problem.

Be aware that in C array indexes are not checked for overflow. If you try to access an array with out of bounds indexes, the behaviour is undefined, anything can happen.
There are at least following problems in your code:

In GaloisMult the dbits array has 11 entries, but the index [10 - abits[i] + bbits[k] can become up to 13 (or even more), hence you have an array overflow which triggers undefined behaviour. The fact that removing the unused array rbits changes the behaviour of your code is a strong indication of an array overflow.
The cipherText and the DecryptedText arrays have a length of 1 so they can hold strings with a maximum length of 0, which is pretty pointless. They should have the same length as the rawInput array, so you want char cipherText[1024] = "";.Hint: declare a constant #define MESSAGE_LENGTH 1024 and use MESSAGE_LENGTH instead of 1024

There may be more problems though, I didn't check.

char cipherText[1024] = ""; solves the first problem but the 2nd rbits problem still remains. as i mentioned
abits[i] for any given i can be at max 7 and bbits[k] will be max 3 so abits[i] + bbits[k] <= 10 hence dbits[10 - 10]  will be max and it cant go above 10

@JaiminVashi the index got to 13 here, check that thoroughly, maby there are more problems in GaloisMult. Use the debugger. Did you try naively int dbits[] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}; ?

i did try printing a and b,a+b they all are in range <=10 but if i do 10 - a + b it goes upto 13

@JaiminVashi don't be mean with your buffer sizes. Using a few extra bytes won't get you a pay cut, but allows for off-by-one errors and so on.

@JaiminVashi well, it seems you've found the problem.

now if i do10 - (abits[i] + bbits[k]) instead of 10 - abits[i] + bbits[k] the program gets stuck in infinite loop

@JaiminVashi that's another problem. The problem in your code was simply an array index overflow. Always check your array indexes, if they are out of bounds all bets are off....

They aren't the same.

i solved the GaloisMult Problem Check My Answer in this post link
